# References to Monty Python's Holy Grail in A Song of Ice and Fire

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, holy-grail, monty-python

In A Dance with Dragons, when the sellswords of the

> Windblown

talk between themselves, one says about  Daenerys' Unsullied that they are

> the kind that don't break and run when you fart in their general direction.

It seems to me a reference to Monty Python's Holy Grail when the insulting Frenchman says to King Arthur and Ser Galahad:

> I fart in your general direction

So, is it a reference to the Holy Grail, and are there any other references in ASoIaF to Monty Python's work?

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I have to admit I missed that one, and I can't recall any other.

Comment: In A Storm of Swords, the wildlings use a giant wooden turtle to attack the wall. It could so easily have been a rabbit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is a reference to Monty Python. GRRM likes to sneak in references to lots of little things.

[TV Tropes has a list of some shoutouts](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ASongOfIceAndFire/TropesSToZ)

One of the funniest ones in my opinion is the [NY Giants vs. Dallas Cowboys "incident"](http://fantasyhotlist.blogspot.no/2012/09/ser-patrek-of-kings-mountain.html). It even has [several layers](http://do.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/10eca8/ser_patrek_of_kings_mountain_was_a_character/c6cutt5) to the joke.

Answer (score 1):

The latest episode of Game of Thrones (S04E03 - [Breaker of Chains](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Breaker_of_Chains)) has a joke where someone says that they pronounced Knight as "knig-git".

**This is reminiscent of the scene below;**

Comment: That's Princess Shireen teaching Davos to read.